# How to combine models and order by model two data in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I would like to be able to output leaders in a section by their position in a group.  I'm thinking of combining these tables through a pivot table ordered by position from the groups table.

These are the three class I have relationships established

```php
class Leader extends Model 
{
   public function groups() 
   {  
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group');
   }
}

class Group extends Model
{
   public function leaders() 
   {  
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\Leader');
   }
}
class GroupLeader extends Model
{
   // Maybe some function here?
}
```

I would like to be able to get the groups in the controller and pass them individually kinda like this.

```php
$group1 = Leader::where('group', '=', 'group1_name')->orderBy('position', 'asc');
$group2 = Leader::where('group', '=', 'group2_name')->orderBy('position', 'asc');

return view('page.leadership')->with([
    'group1' => $group1,
    'group2' => $group2,
]);
```

Then I would pass the variables to include files which would loop through them in order.

Here is my table structure

```php
leaders
--------
| id
| first_name
| last_name
| deceased
----------
groups
----------
| id
| group
| title
| position
-----------
group_leader
-------------
| id 
| group_id
| leader_id
------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
$groups = Leader::whereIn('group', ['group1_name', 'group2_name'])
    ->orderBy('position', 'asc')
    ->groupBy('group', 'id')
    ->get(['group', 'id']);
```